# Link to external stylesheet even after browser is refreshed

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way I can link to an external styelsheet in Google Chrome and then stay linked to it even when the browser is refreshed?

Currently, I am "inspecting element" and then "edit as html" and adding my stylesheet and tweaking a couple of other settings in the source. But when i go to check another page, it is reset.

Any extensions or settings in Chrome Developer tools that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-css/okpjlejfhacmgjkmknjhadmkdbcldfcb/related?hl=en

You click on the button then the css editor comes up. you then add what ever you want to the page and it stays there.

example

[image]

Comment: Does seem to stay when the page is refreshed though

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is native(built in) inside `chrome` as of `v46.0.2490.80`.

Heres how you can do this..

[image: Chrome Local Workspace permanent changes]

What will happen is all the changes that you make to any css/js/html/etc files inside the chrome dev tools, those will be synced to the source file in real-time.
You can read further on this topic [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces).